Transforming from UTM Clarke 1866 Ellipsoid to WGS84 (ASTER Level 2 surface reflectance data)
I have acquired some Level 2 ASTER surface reflectance data however this is in Clarke 1866 Elipsoid, not WGS84. QGIS/GDAL appears to be unable to make this conversion and so far I have not found any alternative means of doing so.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Here is the metadata of one of the .tif files I have acquired:

Size is 4980, 4200
Coordinate System is:
ENGCRS["Universal Transverse Mercator CLARKE 1866 ELLIPSOID",
    EDATUM[""],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
GeoTransform =
  526638.7503035303, 14.83802416268769, -2.198417373361203
  1868731.095055375, -2.198417373361203, -14.83802416268769
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  526638.750, 1868731.095) 
Lower Left  (  517405.397, 1806411.394) 
Upper Right (  600532.111, 1857782.977) 
Lower Right (  591298.758, 1795463.275) 
Center      (  558968.754, 1832097.185) 
Band 1 Block=4980x4200 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray



Can you supply the full coordinate metadata for the data? Or point us to the actual data?

@Spacedman I have added the metadata of one of the files I have. The image name is AST_07XT_00308132003144856_20240409111025_1286846.SurfaceReflectanceVNIR.Band3N, if that is of help too

Does QGIS read this in and locate it correctly, on, for example, an OpenStreetMap background layer? It looks like you've got a rotated TIFF from the GeoTransform matrix but GDAL should understand that. Have you tried the gdal_translate command?

When I import the tifs for each band individually, yes, they land in the right place compared to other imagery I have. However, when I merge them to make a multi-band raster, it's then displaced and rotated. I haven't tried that, no; I'm a bit of a novice with QGIS to be honest so don't know what to do with that command at this point... will read up on it. Thanks for the suggestion :)

I couldn't find a file like this - so unless you can share the file you have I think we're stuck. Its not clear to me how QGIS can locate it in the right place given the info....  But I'd like to try. Can you either link to where you got it from or share it on a dropbox or similar service?

(Sorry for slow response, been away). It's weird that it lands in the right place, I don't get it either. Not sure I have permissions to share it, but it's ASTER surface reflectance data (AS_07XT) acquired from NASA's earthdata platform, captured on August 13th 2003, over the island of Montserrat, Eastern Caribbean.

I have a strong suspicion that the data or more likely the original workflow originated in ArcGIS workstation where the default ellipsoid (spheroid) was Clarke 1866. At that time, the data may not have been accurate enough (or the producers not knowledgeable enough) to assign the actual datum/GeoCRS. It was often really NAD27 but if this data is recent no idea what it might really be. --I've worked at Esri for 30 years.

There are no transformations between Clarke 1866 and anything else because it's not a datum.

The coordinate system is local or "engineering". It is pretty close to common transverse Mercator or UTM but it is missing some critical information. See
https://proj.org/en/9.4/operations/projections/tmerc.html
https://proj.org/en/9.4/operations/projections/utm.html
https://proj.org/en/9.4/usage/ellipsoids.html
By the name of the coordinate system the projection is transverse Mercator and the ellipsoid is Clarke 1866 which Proj knows by name "clrk66".
What is missing is information about where is the origin. We know the coordinates and that they mean Easting and Northing, for example
Upper Left  (  526638.750, 1868731.095)

but without knowing where is the origin (0,0) is is impossible to locate the image on the ground and to make coordinate transformatiotions.
If you can get somewhere the value of the central meridian +lon_0 and the possible false-easting +x_0value it might work to write a Proj string and use that instead of the ENGCRS Well Known Text. If it feels that the zero latitude is not at the equator then +lat_0 is also needed.
+proj=tmerc +lon_0=? +x_0=? +ellps=clrk66

Hand edited UTM can only work if the engineering system is connected with some UTM zone +proj=utm +zone=? +ellps=clrk66.

I've managed to get an hdf file of something like that data and there's a lot of extra metadata. For example, the UTMZONECODE metadata items all say "20" which would be a reasonable UTM zone for that area. You can get all the metadata using the terra::describe function:
> describe("./AST_07XT_00308132003144856_20240423090224_1603470.hdf")
  [1] "Driver: HDF4/Hierarchical Data Format Release 4"                                                                                                        
  [2] "Files: ./AST_07XT_00308132003144856_20240423090224_1603470.hdf"                                                                                         
  [3] "Size is 512, 512"                                                                                                                                       
  [4] "Metadata:" 
...
[345] "  UTMZONECODE1=20"                                                                                                                                      
[346] "  UTMZONECODE10=20"                                                                                                                                     
[347] "  UTMZONECODE11=20"                                                                                 
[etc]

There's also the complication of the data being rotated, which the terra package doesn't deal with but QGIS handles on-the-fly.
Reading a single dataset band from the HDF should give a rotated warning:
> band4 = 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"AST_07XT_00308132003144856_20240423090224_1603470.hdf":SurfaceReflectanceSWIR:Band4'
> r4 = rast(band4)
Warning message:
[rast] the data in this file are rotated. Use 'rectify' to fix that 

But if I then try to rectify this, it crashes R completely:
> r4r = rectify(r4)

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'
[traceback and nasty exit follows]

However, if I first convert to TIFF using gdal command line tools:
$ gdal_translate \
  HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"AST_07XT_00308132003144856_20240423090224_1603470.hdf":SurfaceReflectanceSWIR:Band4 \
  translated.tiff

and then that can be read in and rectified successfully:
> library(terra)
terra 1.7.39
> r4 = rectify(rast("translated.tiff"))
Warning message:
[rast] the data in this file are rotated. Use 'rectify' to fix that 

At this point it has no CRS. We infer it to be UTM 20N from the metadata, so let's assign that:
> crs(r4) = "epsg:32620"
> plot(r4)


Well that looks good but is it in the right place? Let's use mapview, which I thought worked with terra rasters but doesn't, I'll convert to old raster rasters which doesn't change anything substantial but it does look like its in the right place:
> mapview::mapview(raster::raster(r4))


So I think the strategy is:

Use gdal_translate to convert to TIFF (if you are starting with HDF, maybe skip this step if you have a TIFF and the rest of this works). R's gdal tools package might have a function that wraps this command-line tool.
Read in using terra::rast
Rectify using terra::rectify
Assign UTM zone correctly

Note that rectification is (I think) a lossy process, since you are undoing a rotation, so you might need to think carefully about how you do that process.

Phenomenal response. Thank you so much for taking the time to look into the issue and for coming up with a solution. I appreciate it massively... I've since gone and completed the tedious task of georeferencing the image to re-rotate it, so this'll be VERY helpful for the remaining images...
Just to confirm, all the code above is in R? (I've not used R before so this'll be a nice excuse to learn!)

Ah yes I usually only answer R questions so sometimes I assume! Its all R except for the gdal_translate command which is a command-line utility installed with the GDAL suite. Depending on your OS and environment you may have to work out how to run these command-line tools. If you have Python skills you could possibly do this over a number of files from Python within QGIS, since I think its both possible to call GDAL routines and do a load/save operation in PyQGIS...

Thanks! As an update: I've managed to download .tiff files straight from EarthData, with a hope of skipping the .hdf translation step. Got through the steps above to the point where I've rectified it. However, these .tiffs are all delivered assigned to the Clark 1883 CRS. I've tried then reprojecting with terra::project, but much like with QGIS, it cannot find the coordinate operations to make this reprojection... think I will have a go at downloading the .hdf files and then translating them to see what that does...
